# How to evaluate this indefinite integral with exponent and square roots?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

does there exist any way for evaluation of this integral:

$\int \frac{e^{\left(ax+b\sqrt{1+x^2}\right)}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx$

Mathematica suggested to do it with series expansion. However, may be there exist some analytical closed form solution?

Comment: I see the hyperbolic denominator which signals to me a trigonometric substitution. Where is this integral from?

Comment: This integral can arise in some kind of PDE solution in cylindrical coordinates with axial symmetry (x is the axis of symmetry). Indeed the trigonometric (hyperbolic) substitution  $x = \sinh u$ leads to the integral $\int e^{a \sinh u + b \cosh u} du$. Seems, it does not have a closed form solution.

Comment: Maybe use euler identity: exp(iθ)=cosθ+isinθ⇔exp(i[-it])=cos(-it)+isin(-it)=sinh(t)+cosh(t)? This may not work though. Another option is to the use series expansion and convert to special functions or maybe elementary functions after integration.